# ios swift change orientation will change UIView Design

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiview

In My project 
change orientation will change UIView Design for same `ViewController`
Portrait:
[image]

Landscape
[image]

in same ViewController change the design for different orientation styles.

Comment: What is the question?  How to accomplish this?  So the squares don’t just change orientation but position to each other? In IB or code?

Answer (score 4):

The answer you are looking for is UIStackView

[Here is Apple Doc if you really want to go into it](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview)

Implementing UIStackView is easy

1) Select the all views you want to take effect
2) Select Embed in Stackview like displayed in image below

[image: Using UIStackview]

3) Setup your UIStackView

[image]

Here how your UIStackview property will look like.

[image]

UIStackView manage your screen rotation and you can have two different layouts as you desire.

Answer (score 2):

You should look at Size Classes concept.
For example, watch this video on youtube to understand how it works.
https://youtu.be/7iT9fueKCJM

Also you can setup your constraints programmatically after rotation:

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)

        if (UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.isLandscape) {
            // ------ Landscape -----
            // Setup constraints

        } else {
            // ----- Portrait -----
            // Setup constraints
        }
    }
```